# Ubuntu 20.04 Intel with OpenCL 2.1 NEO CPU device not found

Tags: opencl, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed Intel's OpenCL drivers:`intel-opencl-icd`. My CPU type is `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K`, `clinfo` prints information that `Intel(R) OpenCL HD Graphics` GPU device is found, but for some reason there is no CPU device. Why is that? Does `OpenCL NEO` driver not support CPU?

```
  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) OpenCL HD Graphics
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) Gen9 HD Graphics NEO
  Device Vendor                                   Intel(R) Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 2.1 NEO
  Driver Version                                  20.26.17199
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 2.0
  Device Type                                     GPU
```

Comment: NEO is a GPU driver. I am not a Linux expert, but there might be a separate CPU driver elsewhere; there is on Windows.

Comment: Thanks Tim. You are right. I got a CPU driver from Intel's page. It added intel64.icd vendor to `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/` and CPU appeared. I thought NEO would handle both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Tim. NEO is a GPU driver, CPU driver has to be installed independently.